# Trying to auth with Google Account in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I was trying to do like in this official guide from Microsoft  **without success...**

1. I have just created a clean ASP.NET MVC Identity User project.
2. Installed SSL for a permanent port: `https://localhost:44392/`
3. Created the project in Google APIs, got the id & secret key.
4. Uncommented lines in file: `Startup.Auth.cs` code and filled out the data:

   ```
       app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
       {
           ClientId = "111111111111.apps.googleusercontent.com",
           ClientSecret = "11111111111",
           Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
       });
   ```

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOmdI.png) i am trying to auth with google account

And again I'm on the authorization module. What could be the problem? I did everything according to the instructions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX1jF.png)

What should i do? Guys please help me.

Comment: guide from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-onbut